# How to show the selected item in popup menu which is inside a fragment using a check box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, selection, popupmenu

I am using an image button for a popup menu to popup everything is working fine but when I select an item in the menu the item is selected and it doesn't show the selection so that I could identify the selected item.The checkbox remains unchecked even after the selection

```
menu_icon_img=myView.findViewById(R.id.Id_customer_over_flow);
        menu_icon_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
                    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_menu_items, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.show();
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.select_name_a_z:
                                 if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                                    else item.setChecked(true);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.select_name_z_a:
                                    if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                                    else item.setChecked(true);
                                    return true;

                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >
        <group
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/select_name_a_z"
                android:title="@string/name_a_z"
                android:checkable="true"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/select_name_z_a"
                android:title="@string/name_z_a"
                android:checkable="true"
                />
        </group>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating the popup menu from onClick of an imageview. whenever a click event occures  a new instance of popup menu is being created.

to avoid this initiate the popup menu in onCreate method. And call popup.show()  from onClick() method.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar menus are supposed to navigate you the specified activities or fragments on click of the pop up.I am not sure what is the problem , but once you click on any MenuItem it will navigate you to given Intent associated with the the id for example,

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.select_name_a_z:
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.this);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    return true;
```

If you are using a checkable menu item then change the below code from

```
 case R.id.select_name_z_a:
                 if (item.isChecked()) 
                     item.setChecked(false);
                 else item.setChecked(true);
                      return true;
```

Do like

```
if (!item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(true);
```

Because item.ischecked() is false in the beginning state.

Comment: As far as I know the popup menu is used to select an item from the menu and do necessary operations according to the selection it can be any action navigation,sorting,color change ... but here my problem is I can't identify my selection after an item is selected the check box remains unchecked

Comment: To set checkboxes selected you need to store the value stored in sharedpreferences boolean .The below code will loose it's state after the activity or fragment is paused or stopped which will happen once you click and start  the intent,  ````case R.id.select_name_z_a:
                                    if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                                    else item.setChecked(true);
                                    return true;````

Comment: I am not using Intent here I only need the selection to be appeared when I am active in that particular fragment I don't mind losing the selection when I switch  fragments.Simply I need the checkbox to be checked based on my selection

Comment: See my updated answer, but you can see the checkbox selection for a fraction of a second.

Comment: I need the check box to be checked so that the user understands which item is selected by him so it should be checked  until  the fragment is active.I have inserted my menu xml to the question for some clarity

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your above code, Try this

```
menu_icon_img=findViewById(R.id.Id_customer_over_flow);
popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), menu_icon_img);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_menu_items, popup.getMenu());

menu_icon_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (this != null) {
            popup.show();
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
                    for(int i = 0;i<menu.size();i++){
                        menu.getItem(i).setChecked(false);
                    }
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also for all items in menu set:

> android:checkable="true"

Comment: you can place your code inside onMenuItemClick after for loop.

Comment: @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
                    for(int i = 0;i<menu.size();i++){
                        menu.getItem(i).setChecked(false);
                    }
                    switch(item.getItemId()){ }
                    return true;
                }
            });